# Trouble activating PWM on PA6 of Orange Pi One using DTSO and WiringOP

Tags: device-tree, pwm, orange-pi, armbian

I'm attempting to activate PWM on pin PA6 of an Orange Pi One board. I've tried using a Device Tree Blob Overlay (DTBO) and accessing the sysfs interface, as well as using the WiringOP library, but I'm encountering issues.

I'm using Armbian 23.08.0-trunk Bookworm with Linux 6.4.1-sunxi.

For the DTSO approach, I've created the following DTSO file:

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
    compatible = "allwinner,sun8i-h3";

    fragment@0 {
        target-path = "/chosen";
        __overlay__ {
            /delete-property/ stdout-path;
        };
    };

    fragment@1 {
        target = <&uart0>;
        __overlay__ {
            status = "disabled";
        };
    };

    fragment@2 {
        target = <&pio>;
        __overlay__ {
            pwm0_pin: pwm0 {
                pins = "PA6";
                function = "pwm0";
            };
        };
    };

    fragment@3 {
        target = <&pwm>;
        __overlay__ {
            pinctrl-names = "default";
            pinctrl-0 = <&pwm0_pin>;
            status = "okay";
        };
    };
};
```

I've exported the PWM in sysfs and configured it with the following commands:

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0/export;
echo 10000000 > /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0/pwm0/period;
echo 5000000 > /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0/pwm0/period;
echo 1 > /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0/pwm0/enable
```

However, I'm not getting any output from the board.

When attempting to use the WiringOP library, I receive the message:

> OrangePi Pi wiringPi PWM test program
> the pin you choose is not surport hardware PWM
> you can select PI3 for PWM pin
> or you can use it in softPwm mode
> please use soft pwmmode or choose PWM pin

According to the processor's documentation, there should be PWM support on this pin. I'm unsure of what to do next.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to successfully enable PWM on PA6 of the Orange Pi One board.